# Use ExceptionHelper class as an Attribute/Extension/Property for a Method/Class level in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, attributes

Currently I have a `Exception helper Class`

```
public class ExceptionHelper
    {
        public static void Catch(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log error and thorw
                // Do what you want
            }
        }      
    }
```

This is used to wrap methods in other classes to catch and logs exceptions like this

```
public static class RepoManger1
    {
        public static void TestMethod(string something)
        {
            ExceptionHelper.Catch(() =>
            {
                Int32 testvar1 = 10;
                Int32 testvar2 = 0;
                Int32 testvar3 = testvar1 / testvar2;
            });
        }
    }
```

I am thinking of converting this to an `Attribute` that can be defined on a `class or method`
so that i do not have to write this code on every method.

Any other approach can also be suggested for the same

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are meant to provide extra information about a class or method, while, if I understood correctly, you would like methods with your attribute to be automatically wrapped in your exception handling code, which is not possible.

In my opinion, the best thing to do here would be something like this:

```
public class ExceptionHelper {
    public static void ProcessException(Exception exc) {
        // common exception handling code 
        // e.g. log error, but DO NOT throw
    }
}

public static class RepoManger1 {
    public static void TestMethod(string something) {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            ExceptionHelper.ProcessException(exc);
            // if necessary, re-throw the exception HERE, so that
            // people reading your code can see that the exception 
            // is being re-thrown
            throw;                      
        }
    }
}
```

I think that this is much more readable than your previous approach (and of any possible solution involving attributes). When I look at this code, I immediately understand that you are catching an exception and doing something with it, in the other cases it would take a while to figure it out.

Comment: Can i use any different approach for the same.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Very interesting, thanks. Does Postsharp modify the code you write to add boilerplate parts?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this looks promising, checking it out.

Comment: Postsharp decompiles your code after normal .NET compilation, then weaves in code from the attributes you've created (attributes inheriting from Postsharp base classes), and then recompiles the code. You can specify things to happen on entry, exit, exceptions, etc. You can relatively easily add logging, custom exception handling, authentication, security, as well as apply patterns to classes, like INotifyPropertyChanged and similar.